# Using python to parse the getEmailActivityUserDetail report

Tags: python, dictionary, parsing

I'm using a python script, to pull data from https://graph.microsoft.com.  The output that is delivered duplicates itself (10) times for each parsed user.  What step is missing to only capture the requested once?

```
    import requests
    import urllib
    import json
    import csv
    import os
    
    client_id = urllib.parse.quote_plus("#######################")
    client_secret = urllib.parse.quote_plus("######################")
    tenant = urllib.parse.quote_plus("#########################")
    
    auth_uri = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/" + tenant + "/oauth2/v2.0/token"
    auth_body = "grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=" + client_id + "&client_secret=" + client_secret + "&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2F.default"
    
    authorization = requests.post(auth_uri, data=auth_body, headers={"Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"})
    token = json.loads(authorization.content)['access_token']
    
    graph_uri = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/reports/getEmailActivityUserDetail(period=%27D30%27)"
    response = requests.get(graph_uri, data=auth_body, headers={'Content-Type': "application/json", 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token})
    
    print(response.text)
    
    temp_usr_list = [
    'User.One@domain.com',
    'User.Two@domain.com'
    ]
    
    report_user_list = []
    
    for line in response.iter_lines():
    
        line_fields = line.decode("utf-8").split(',')
    
        for entry in line_fields:
            if len(entry) < 1:
                continue
    
            if line_fields[1] in temp_usr_list:
                d = dict(
                    user_principle_name = line_fields[1],
                    send_count = line_fields[6],
                    recv_count = line_fields[7],
                    read_count = line_fields[8],
                    assigned_products = line_fields[9]
                )
    
                report_user_list.append(d)
    
    print(report_user_list)
```

**OUTPUT:**

{'user_principle_name': 'User.One@domain.com', 'send_count': '0', 'recv_count': '0', 'read_count': '0', 'assigned_products': 'MICROSOFT'},...

{'user_principle_name': 'User.Two@domain.com', 'send_count': '0', 'recv_count': '0', 'read_count': '0', 'assigned_products': 'MICROSOFT'},...

Answer (score 1):

Try running it once in this format and let me know if you get the same output.

```
import requests
import urllib
import json
import csv
import os

# Parms

client_id = urllib.parse.quote_plus('#######################')
client_secret = urllib.parse.quote_plus('######################')
tenant = urllib.parse.quote_plus('#########################')

auth_uri = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/' + tenant \
    + '/oauth2/v2.0/token'
auth_body = 'grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=' + client_id \
    + '&client_secret=' + client_secret \
    + '&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2F.default'

authorization = requests.post(auth_uri, data=auth_body,
                              headers={'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
                              })
token = json.loads(authorization.content)['access_token']

graph_uri = \
    'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/reports/getEmailActivityUserDetail(period=%27D30%27)'
response = requests.get(graph_uri, data=auth_body,
                        headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token})

print response.text

temp_usr_list = ['User.One@domain.com', 'User.Two@domain.com']

report_user_list = []

for line in response.iter_lines():

    line_fields = line.decode('utf-8').split(',')

    for entry in line_fields:
        if len(entry) < 1:
            continue

    if line_fields[1] in temp_usr_list:
        d = dict(user_principle_name=line_fields[1],
                 send_count=line_fields[6],
                 recv_count=line_fields[7],
                 read_count=line_fields[8],
                 assigned_products=line_fields[9])

        report_user_list.append(d)

print report_user_list
```

Comment: The only thing I see you changed was at the temp_user_list

FROM:
temp_usr_list = [
'User.One@domain.com',
'User.Two@domain.com',
]

TO:
temp_usr_list = ['User.One@domain.com', 'User.Two@domain.com']

If so, the report still produces (10) duplicate User.One and User.Two outputs.

Comment: @Ottomate On my end, I noticed an indentation issue and everything is parsing now as it should.

Comment: @Otto I took a guess that your `for entry in line_fields` loop was meant to skip any `line` with any empty field. With that assumption, it looked like your next code block was still indented under that loop. My edit moved that block outside of that second loop.

Comment: Removing the indent for report_user_list.append(d) does remove duplicates, but it also removes any additional users output.  The intent of the script is to pull all email data and then creates a dictionary of selected columes for the temp_user_list users.

Comment: @Ottomate How does it remove additional users? You're intentionally constraining to a users list. It appears `user_principle_name` is the element at index `1` in `line_fields`. This is unique to `line`, not `entry`.  All the second for-loop does is skip any `line` with an empty string between commas. If you want the additional `user_principle_name`s, stop artificially constraining - remove the check to see if its in `tmp_usr_list`. Have I misunderstood something?

Comment: @That1Guy The script doesn't actually remove the additional users found in the temp_user_list when I remove the indent of report_user_list.append(d), but it doesn't print the output after the first user.

A generic view of the intended purpose I'm trying to solve:
1. Capture email data from microsoft - Done
2. Output email data - Done
3. Provide a  list of selected users - Done
4. Provide a list of columns to capture for users - Done
5. Output list  of only the selected list of users and columns - Pending

Comment: @Ottomate Something here is unclear - and I don't know on which end the misunderstanding is coming from. Please `print(line)` and share an example here. The criteria for printing output (being included in `report_user_list`) is that the `user_principle_name` is in `temp_usr_list` *and* there isn't an empty string in your `line_fields` list. Nothing else is preventing other entries from showing up.

Comment: @That1Guy Using the following code block, with the removed indent, this is the OUTPUT:  

2021-11-07,User.One@domain.com,User One,False,,2021-11-06,0,0,0,EXCHANGE,0,0  
2021-11-07,User.Two@domain.com,User Two,False,,2021-11-06,0,0,0,OFFICE,0,0  
2021-11-07,User.Three@domain.com,User Three,False,,2021-11-06,0,0,0,OFFICE,0,0  
2021-11-07,User.Four@domain.com,User Four,False,,2021-11-07,0,0,0,MICROSOFT,0,0  
{'user_principle_name': 'User.Three@domain.com', 'send_count': '0', 'recv_count': '0', 'read_count': '0', 'assigned_products': 'OFFICE'}

Comment: <code>
    for entry in line_fields:
        if len(entry) < 1:
            continue
        if line_fields[1] in temp_usr_list:
            d = dict(
                user_principle_name = line_fields[1],
                send_count = line_fields[6],
                recv_count = line_fields[7],
                read_count = line_fields[8],
                assigned_products = line_fields[9]
            )
report_user_list.append(d)
print(report_user_list)
</code>

Comment: @Ottomate So you're missing `User.Three@domain.com` and `User.Four@domain.com` because they're not in `temp_usr_list`. What am I missing? There are no duplicates, and you're getting exactly what you're asking for. To get 3 and 4, either include them in `temp_usr_list` or remove the check to get every user. Its painfully difficult to decipher your output because its in a comment, but it looks like there is only one user per `line`. The only rows you're "missing" are the ones you're explicitly excluding by your `if line_fields[1] in temp_usr_list` check.

Comment: @That1Guy Thanks, you've been helpful.  StackOverflow markup (...and python) is causing me some issues.  Let me try and clean up the threads to give a clearer discription if the issue.

Comment: @Mark Rotteveel, etc. 
My issue was not, is not answered to date.  Due to my limited access to edit the current answer and/or to provide a clear example in a comment (because it wraps), this issue can be removed to avoid confusion for any future searches.